# My code works on windows but fails on linux. Eror: premature end of file bmp

Tags: c, linux, padding, bmp

I have to work with some bmp files in order to change the colour of some pixels in a new colour; the withe pixels are ignored. My code seems to work on windows but once I try it on linux the new bmp file wont open because 'premature end of file bmp'.
The input file contains the name of the bmp file and the new colour of the pixels.
I have to create a new file with '_task1.bmp' at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct bmp_fileheader
{
    unsigned char  fileMarker1; /* 'B' */
    unsigned char  fileMarker2; /* 'M' */
    unsigned int   bfSize; /* File's size */
    unsigned short unused1;
    unsigned short unused2;
    unsigned int   imageDataOffset; /* Offset to the start of image data */
}FH;
typedef struct bmp_infoheader
{
    unsigned int   biSize; /* Size of the info header - 40 bytes */
    signed int     width; /* Width of the image */
    signed int     height; /* Height of the image */
    unsigned short planes;
    unsigned short bitPix;
    unsigned int   biCompression;
    unsigned int   biSizeImage; /* Size of the image data */
    int            biXPelsPerMeter;
    int            biYPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int   biClrUsed;
    unsigned int   biClrImportant;
}IH;
int main()
{
    FH fh;    IH ih;
    FILE *f,*g;
    int B,G,R,i,j,padding;
    char fileName[22],fileNameTask[22],*p;
    unsigned char clr[3],clrNew[3];

    f=fopen("input100.txt","rt");
    if(f==NULL)
        return -1;

    fscanf(f,"%s %d %d %d",&fileName,&B,&G,&R);
    clrNew[0]=B; clrNew[1]=G; clrNew[2]=R;
    fclose(f);

    f=fopen(fileName,"rb");
    if(f==NULL)
        return -1;

    p=strchr(fileName,'.');   *p='\0';
    strcpy(fileNameTask,fileName); strcat(fileNameTask,"_task1.bmp");

    g=fopen(fileNameTask,"wb");
    fread(&fh.fileMarker1,1,1,f); fread(&fh.fileMarker2,1,1,f); // B M
    fread(&fh.bfSize,4,1,f);
    fread(&fh.unused1,2,1,f); fread(&fh.unused1,2,1,f);
    fread(&fh.imageDataOffset,4,1,f);

    fwrite(&fh.fileMarker1,1,1,g); fwrite(&fh.fileMarker2,1,1,g);
    fwrite(&fh.bfSize,4,1,g);
    fwrite(&fh.unused1,2,1,g); fread(&fh.unused1,2,1,g);
    fwrite(&fh.imageDataOffset,4,1,g);

    fread(&ih.biSize,4,1,f); // 40
    fread(&ih.width,4,1,f); fread(&ih.height,4,1,f);
    fread(&ih.planes,2,1,f);
    fread(&ih.bitPix,2,1,f); // 24
    fread(&ih.biCompression,4,1,f);
    fread(&ih.biSizeImage,4,1,f);
    fread(&ih.biXPelsPerMeter,4,1,f); fread(&ih.biYPelsPerMeter,4,1,f); // 0
    fread(&ih.biClrUsed,4,1,f);   fread(&ih.biClrImportant,4,1,f); // ambele 0

    fwrite(&ih.biSize,4,1,g); // 40
    fwrite(&ih.width,4,1,g); fwrite(&ih.height,4,1,g);
    fwrite(&ih.planes,2,1,g);
    fwrite(&ih.bitPix,2,1,g); // 24
    fwrite(&ih.biCompression,4,1,g);
    fwrite(&ih.biSizeImage,4,1,g);
    fwrite(&ih.biXPelsPerMeter,4,1,g); fwrite(&ih.biYPelsPerMeter,4,1,g); // 0
    fwrite(&ih.biClrUsed,4,1,g);   fwrite(&ih.biClrImportant,4,1,g); // ambele 0
    padding=(ih.width*3) % 4;
    for(i=0;i<ih.height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<ih.width;j++)
        {
            fread(&clr,3,1,f);
            if(clr[0]==255 && clr[1]==255 && clr[2]==255)
                fwrite(clr,3,1,g);
            else
                fwrite(clrNew,3,1,g);
        }
        switch(padding)
        {
            case 3: fread(&clr,1,1,f); clr[0]=0; fwrite(&clr,1,1,g); break;
            case 2: fread(&clr,2,1,f); clr[0]=clr[1]=0; fwrite(&clr,2,1,g); break;
            case 1: fread(&clr,3,1,f); clr[0]=clr[1]=clr[2]=0; fwrite(&clr,3,1,g);
        }
    }
    fclose(f); fclose(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try opening a binary file in binary mode.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Maybe you could see the difference in files created on Linux and Windows when you open them in a hex editor. This would also give great hints where to look into your code.

Answer (score 4):

Note POSIX do not have `t` in file opening modes. It's specific to Windows. If you want it to work, use `b`:

```
f=fopen("input100.txt","rb");
                         ^
```

Actually, ISO C do not have `t`. The only flags defined by ISO C are `b` and `+`. Pay special attention to those when attempting to write portable code.